# How to get Keypress event in QWebView window

Tags: qt, qt4, qwebview, qwebkit

I am using QWebView to display some flash content in this. I have been set the attribute of this window to be frameless and made it as a child window of some other process(Remote desktop Terminal session window).

I wanted to grab the ALT+F4 key press combination on this flash video. I mean to say if user clicks on the flash video(i.e. my QWebView window is in focus now), at that time if user presses ALT+F4, then I wanted to take some action on this event.

I have overridden keypressevent(QKeyEvent), but I am not getting this to be called , even though after setting the focus policy.

**NOTE :- I am getting key press event only and only when user click on the QWebView window outside the flash area.**